# Removing old versions of gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

For some gems on my machine, there are multiple versions:

```
$gem list bigdecimal
bigdecimal (1.2.6, 1.2.5)

$gem list io-console
io-console (0.4.3, 0.4.2)

$gem list json
json (1.8.2, 1.8.1)

...
```

I want to remove the old versions. I tried several commands:

```
$gem cleanup
Cleaning up installed gems...
Clean Up Complete

$sudo gem cleanup
Cleaning up installed gems...
Clean Up Complete

$gem cleanup json
Cleaning up installed gems...
Clean Up Complete

$sudo gem cleanup json
Cleaning up installed gems...
Clean Up Complete
```

but the old versions are not removed. Why are the old versions not detected by `cleanup`? How can I remove them?

**Update** Strange thing is that, I can manually uninstall the newer versions but not the old ones. For example,

```
$ sudo gem uninstall json --version 1.8.1
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    gem "json" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem

$ sudo gem uninstall json --version 1.8.2
Successfully uninstalled json-1.8.2
```

**Update** What is a default gem? Why can't it be deleted?

**Update** If I have a default old version, does it mean that a newer version is not in use and the default one is called by the command `require`?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that `gem cleanup` isn't working because you have something installed with dependencies on these old versions. You can check what has dependencies on your old gems by running `gem  dependency  your-gem-name --reverse-dependencies`.

If that command doesn't show you any dependencies you can manually remove the old versions with `gem uninstall`:

```
# remove specific version
gem uninstall your-gem-name --version 2.1.0

# remove all versions less than a certain version
gem uninstall your-gem-name --version '<2.1.0'
```

Comment: I tried `$ sudo gem uninstall json --version 1.8.1`, and it gives
`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    gem "json" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem`.

Comment: It's dangerous to uninstall default gems. That's why it's not letting you uninstall the oldest version.